# ADODB Connection giving an undefined error

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4QFC.png)I've set up a macro in an excel workbook that will run some queries in an Access DB and copy the returned records in excel.

While it has been working fine so far it stopped today giving me an unspecified error in the line that is supposed to be opening the connection

The funny thing is that the macro works if I use it on an empty excel workbook-but can't move it there since I need it on the initial template workbook I've set up (20 sheets full of formulas)

Here's my code if someone has any idea why

```
    Sub Query_CompanyParent(ByVal xQueryName As String, ByVal xParaCompany As String, ByVal xParaParent As String, _
                ByVal xDestnSheet As String, ByVal xDestnRange As String)

Dim cn As Object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim AppPath As String

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    'AppPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    AppPath = "MyPath"

    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AppPath & "My database;"

    Debug.Print strConnection

    cn.Open strConnection ' this is where the debugger points me


    Const adCmdStoredProc As Long = 4
    Const adParamInput   As Long = 1
    Const adDate As Long = 7
    Const adVarChar As Long = 200


    cmd.CommandText = xQueryName

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("[Company:]", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, xParaCompany)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("[Parent:]", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, xParaParent)
    End With

    Set rs = cmd.Execute()
    Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, c As Long
    Dim MyField, Location As Range

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xDestnSheet).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xDestnSheet).Activate

   Set Location = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xDestnSheet).Range(xDestnRange)
Rw = Location.Row
    Col = Location.Column
    c = Col

      For Each MyField In rs.Fields      'Header of the results
        Cells(Rw, c) = MyField.Name
        c = c + 1
    Next MyField

    Rw = Rw + 1
    c = Col

    Do Until rs.EOF
        For Each MyField In rs.Fields
                Cells(Rw, c) = MyField
                c = c + 1
        Next MyField

        rs.MoveNext
        Rw = Rw + 1
        c = Col
    Loop


    'Set database objects to nothing
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing


    End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: `AppPath = "MyPath"` needs to be an actual path, not `MyPath` - and you will probably need to change `My database` to the actual name of your database.

Comment: Can you share what strConnection resolves as? Also, I have seen situations where ADO becomes "unreferenced" in Excel. From a VBA window, go to Tools > References and make sure excel sees ADO.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are trying to use an `OLEDB` Provider on an `ADODB` object, which is not going to work.

Comment: @braX How should my object creation look as ? I am so confused because the same connection setup works fine in a different workbook, connecting to the exact same DB.

Comment: @braX my Database and path are actual db/path respectively.Just couldn't share them online

Comment: https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/ado-sql-macros-connecting-database/

Comment: Maybe try another driver as well


Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=[FullPathWithACCDBName]"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "SQL STATEMENT", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

Comment: What error message is being returned? Another possibility is that there is a file locking issue. (i.e. opening the connection in one function is locking the file for the other). Maybe open the connections read only, or remark out the other function and reboot to test.

Comment: @DanielG I've tried your above solution but can't really work it out.How do I set my connection to ready only?

Comment: Can you see if this helps please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941487/open-adodb-connection-to-excel-file-in-read-only-mode

Comment: I think the "mode" property may be what you are looking for. The ADO connection string accepts numerous parameters.

Comment: @DanielG tried playing around with the mode property but still no luck.I've googled around and there's seems to be many unresolved cases. I cannot understand how the same macro works in an empty workbook but not in my template.Frustrating

Comment: I know this sounds crazy, but wondering if deleting and recreating the macro will work, or even the spreadsheet itself (assuming that's not a major task). It's like there is a cached artifact or something. As you say, it used to work, so it must be an internal Excel or ADODB issue.

Comment: @DanielG. Recreating the workbook would unfortunately be a massive task. Got over 15 tabs all with formulas etc. Any idea how to clear that cache if possible? It is driving me crazy!

Comment: @DanielG right I am losing my mind here. While rebuilding the workbook (a days worth of work) the connection was working fine. And then... it stopped!Giving me the same error!

Comment: Wow, that is odd. I have seen this before but unfortunately do not know how to prevent it. So you're going through this. Is there a way to programatically drop and recreate the connection? Please let me know as I am very curious as well.

Comment: @DanielG. After almost throwing my laptop out of the window, I copied the macro in a clean worksheet but without any formulas as the previous template I was working on. I wrote a second macro to copy over the extracted data in the template and it works now. Can't really understand what is preventing it from pulling the data directly in the template workbook.